# How can I disable jumping when hitting an object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-engine, game-development

I am creating a Jump & Run game in 2D and I want to disable jumping for a section in the level. I am not sure how I can do it. This is my code for jumping:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
    {
        characterRb.velocity = new Vector2(characterRb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    }
        
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && characterRb.velocity.y > 0f)
    {
        characterRb.velocity = new Vector2(characterRb.velocity.x, characterRb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
    }
}

private bool IsGrounded()
{
    return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
}
```

I think I would use the OnTriggerEnter2D method for hitting the object and include another boolean in the if statement in the update method but that doesn't sound very clean tho :D

I hope someone can help me out :)

Kind regards

Comment: If you're talking about an "infinite runner" style game, do you know the 'x' values where you want the player not to be able to jump? If so, you could just check to make sure the player location is within the [x1..x2] range, and disable the jump. Or have a set of these, and load the next one in sequence. But this depends on the style of game. If it's more a platform game, you could surround the area with a collider that you OnTriggerEnter2D and OnTriggerExit2D, and disable/enable your player jump accordingly, as you surmised.

Answer (score 0):

I think. When the character jumps and interacts with an object, does disable jumping? Anyways

add bool and Collider2D stuffs

for example :

```
    public bool canJump = true;
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")) {
            canJump = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")) {
            canJump = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and also you can add `if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())` replace with this `if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded() && canJump)`

If you wish, take a look at the documents of the things like Colliders and bool stuffs

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html
and
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html